# Firebase dependencies, firebase-crash:10.0.1'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Please if anyone have any explanation regarding this, then help me understand.

The Issue is:

If in dependencies I'm using this,

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
```

then the below code is not visible, in the layout.

```
  <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_7dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_7dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

But if I'm downgrading the firebase, like this,

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
```

Then the below code is visible.

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_7dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

This is my app dependencies.

```
   dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
        compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my Project's dependencies.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: @Shekar please post your gradle dependency

Comment: I pasted the dependencies.

Comment: Sagar-Gangawane, I found the solution for this. Kindly check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue.

In our MainActivity, initialize the PagerTabStrip like this.

```
PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_header);

((ViewPager.LayoutParams) pagerTabStrip.getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;
```

**One thing to keep in mind is that it will not show any effect on the Preview of the layout. But, if you run, then you will be able to see the correct output in your device.**